# ¿Cómo agregar elementos a un renglón existente de un DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable

Tengo una tabla que se llena con varios datos (ver imagen), pero al llenase pueden quedar espacios vacíos (NO SERIE).
Al hacer una segunda pasada quiero recorrer el DataTable y cuando llegue a los espacios vacíos colocarles un valor (el método que hace eso ya lo tengo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que uso para recorrer el DataTable y encontrar los espacios vacíos es el siguiente:

```
// Le paso el DataTable que ya fue llenado
public void ValidarNoSerie(System.Data.DataTable DataTableCDD)
{
    // Recorro el DataTable
    for (int i = 0; i < DataTableCDD.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        // Asigno el valor del NO SERIE del DataTable a una variable
        string noserie = DataTableCDD.Rows[i]["NO SERIE"].ToString();
        // Verifico si la variable es vacía
        if ((noserie == null) || (noserie == "") || (noserie.Length < 1))
        {
            // Si la variable es vacía, manda llamar el método donde le genera un número
            noserie = GenerarNoSerie(noserie, DataTableCDD);
           // Aquí es donde quiero saber como agrego el valor generado
           // al DataTable en el espacio que detectó como vacío
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactamente lo mismo para extraerlo, pero al contrario

```
noserie = GenerarNoSerie(noserie, DataTableCDD);
DataTableCDD.Rows[i]["NO SERIE"] = noserie;
```